# Run multiple mocha test files with scripts in between

Tags: mocha.js

I'd like to run multiple test files with a single report file (xunit). The catch is that I'd like to run shell/python scripts that re-configure my test bed in between the test file runs.

this works but without shell script
mocha script1.js script2.js -R xunit

I would like:
mocha script1 -R xunit
./myscript.sh
mocha script3 -R xunit

but I would like the output of script1 and script 2 to be a single report.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha has good support for [glob patterns](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/02/07/mocha-glob-pattern/), and in this case you should be able to do:

`mocha ./script* -R xunit`